# Azure Data Factory pipelines are failing when no files available in the source

Tags: azure-data-factory

Currently – we do our data loads from Hadoop on-premise server to SQL DW [ via ADF Staged Copy and DMG on-premise server]. We noticed that ADF pipelines are failing – when there are no files in the  Hadoop on-premise server location [ we do not expect our upstreams to send the files everyday and hence its valid scenario to have ZERO files on  Hadoop on-premise server location ].

Do you have a solution for this kind of scenario ?

Error message given below

> Failed execution Copy activity encountered a user error:
> ErrorCode=UserErrorFileNotFound,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot
> find the 'HDFS' file.
> ,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The
> remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.,Source=System,'.

Thanks,
Aravind

Answer (score 2):

This Requirement can be solved by using the ADFv2 Metadata Task to check for file existence and then skip the copy activity if the file or folder does not exist:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity

Answer (score 1):

You can change the File Path Type to Wildcard, add the name of the file and add a "*" at the end of the name or any other place that suits you.

[image: Options in ADF]

This is a simple way to stop the Pipeline failing when there is no file.

Comment: This will still report an error if the source directory is empty. I added a placeholder file to ensure the directory is never empty and then this method works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Input DataSet for your pipeline? See if you can skip your Input Dataset dependency..

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm, this is a tricky one. I'll up vote the question I think.

Couple of options that I can think of here...

**1)** I would suggest the best way would be to create a custom activity ahead of the copying to check the source directory first. This could handle the behaviour if there isn't a file present, rather than just throwing an error. You could then code this to be a little more graceful when it returns and not block the downstream ADF activities.

**2)** Use some PowerShell to inspect the ADF activity for the missing file error. Then simply set the dataset slice to either skipped or ready using the cmdlet to override the status.

For example:

```
Set-AzureRmDataFactorySliceStatus `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
    -DataFactoryName $ADFName.DataFactoryName `
    -DatasetName $Dataset.OutputDatasets `
    -StartDateTime $Dataset.WindowStart `
    -EndDateTime $Dataset.WindowEnd `
    -Status "Ready" `
    -UpdateType "Individual"
```

This of course isn't ideal, but would be quicker to develop than a custom activity using Azure Automation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Im getting ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidParquetFile,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException. 

how to skip all the errors and proceed processing the next file if available?

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm late to the party, but if you're like me and running into this issue, looks like they made an update a while back to allow for no files found
[image: allow now files fiybd]